# mediaplayer with notification in android java

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I've developed a media player that plays music and displays a notification with controls for play, pause next, and previous functions. I need the app to play its notification in media player just like Spotify thanks in advance

[this is my current notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBG7q.jpg)
[this is the work i intented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dg1j7.jpg)

my BackgroundMusicService

```
package com.example.knowyourtemple.view.service;

import static androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.TAG;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle;

import com.example.knowyourtemple.MainActivity;
import com.example.knowyourtemple.R;

import java.io.IOException;

public class BackgroundMusicService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
    public static final String ACTION_START = "com.example.knowyourtemple.START";
    public static final String ACTION_PAUSE = "com.example.knowyourtemple.PAUSE";
    public static final String ACTION_RESUME = "com.example.knowyourtemple.RESUME";
    public static final String ACTION_SEEK = "com.example.knowyourtemple.SEEK";
    public static final String ACTION_PREVIOUS = "com.example.knowyourtemple.PREVIOUS";
    public static final String ACTION_NEXT = "com.example.knowyourtemple.NEXT";
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private String currentSongName;
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "background_music_channel";
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private MediaSessionCompat mediaSession;

    private boolean isPlaying = false;
    private int currentPosition;
    private int duration;
    private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();
    private MusicPlayerCallback callback;
    private Fragment fragment;

    public void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    public interface MusicPlayerCallback {
        void onPrepared(int duration);

        void onProgress(int progress, int max);

        void onNextSong();

        void onPreviousSong();

        void onResumeSong();

        void onPauseSong();
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public BackgroundMusicService getService() {
            return BackgroundMusicService.this;
        }
    }

    public void setCallback(MusicPlayerCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public MusicPlayerCallback getCallback() {
        return callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(this, "BackgroundMusicService");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Background Music", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent != null) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action != null) {
                if (action.equals(ACTION_START)) {
                    String fileName = intent.getStringExtra("FileName");
                    String songName = intent.getStringExtra("SongName");
                    int startPosition = intent.getIntExtra("StartPosition", 0);
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(startPosition);

                    startMusic(fileName, songName);
                } else if (action.equals(ACTION_PAUSE)) {
                    pauseMusic();
                } else if (action.equals(ACTION_RESUME)) {
                    resumeMusic();
                } else if (action.equals(ACTION_SEEK)) {
                    int position = intent.getIntExtra("Position", 0);
                    seekToPosition(position);
                } else if (action.equals(ACTION_NEXT)) {
                    playNextSong();
                } else if (action.equals(ACTION_PREVIOUS)) {
                    playPreviousSong();
                }
            }
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public void pauseMusic() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            isPlaying = false;
            mediaSession.setActive(false);
            showNotification();

            if (callback != null) {
                callback.onPauseSong();
            }
        }
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }

    public void resumeMusic() {
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            isPlaying = true;
            mediaSession.setActive(true);
            showNotification();

            if (callback != null) {
                callback.onResumeSong();
            }
        }
        updateNotificationProgressPeriodically();
    }

    private void playPreviousSong() {
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onPreviousSong();
        }
    }

    public void playNextSong() {
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onNextSong();
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    public void startMusic(String fileName, String songName) {
        if (fileName != null) {
            isPlaying = true;
            currentSongName = songName;
            Log.d(TAG, "startMusic: " + currentSongName);
            int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(fileName, "raw", getPackageName());
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + resourceId);

            try {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void seekToPosition(int position) {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(position);
            showNotification();
        }
    }

    public int getCurrentPosition() {
        return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        duration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        // Notify the callback that the media player is prepared
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onPrepared(duration);
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
        showNotification();
        updateNotificationProgressPeriodically();

        if (currentPosition > 0) {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition);
            currentPosition = 0; // Reset the saved position
        }
    }

    private void updateNotificationProgressPeriodically() {
        // Create a new Runnable that will update the progress and post it with a delay of 1 second
        Runnable progressUpdateRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Update the progress of the SeekBar in the notification
                showNotification();

                // Post the same Runnable again after a delay of 1 second
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };

        // Start the periodic progress update
        handler.post(progressUpdateRunnable);
    }

 
 private void showNotification() {
     // Create the notification channel (if needed)
     createNotificationChannel();

     int progress = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
     int max = mediaPlayer.getDuration();

     if (callback != null) {
         callback.onProgress(progress, max);
     }

     // Create the remote views for the custom layout
     RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_layout);

     contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.subtitleTextView, currentSongName);

     // Set the progress bar
     contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.progressSeekBar, max, progress, false);

     // Set the playback buttons
     contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_previousButton, createPendingIntent(ACTION_PREVIOUS));

     String action = isPlaying ? ACTION_PAUSE : ACTION_RESUME;
     int playPauseIconResId = isPlaying ? R.drawable.baseline_pause_24 : R.drawable.baseline_play_arrow_24;

     contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_playPauseButton, createPendingIntent(action));
     contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_playPauseButton, playPauseIconResId);
     contentView.setInt(R.id.notification_playPauseButton, "setImageResource", playPauseIconResId);

     contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_nextButton, createPendingIntent(ACTION_NEXT));

     // Create the pending intent for the notification
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

     // Create the notification builder
     NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
             .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_music_note)
             .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
             .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
             .setShowWhen(false)
             .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
             .setCustomContentView(contentView)
             .setOngoing(true); // Set the notification as ongoing (cannot be dismissed by the user)

     // Set the large icon
     Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_music_icon);
     builder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);

     // Update the notification
     notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
 }


    private PendingIntent createPendingIntent(String action) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BackgroundMusicService.class);
        intent.setAction(action);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        } else {
            return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }
    }



    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "Background Music Channel";
            String description = "Channel for background music playback";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
        mediaSession.release();
        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

this is fragment

```
package com.example.knowyourtemple.view.activity;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.example.knowyourtemple.R;
import com.example.knowyourtemple.businesslogic.pojo.PojoMusic;
import com.example.knowyourtemple.databinding.FragmentPlayMusicBinding;
import com.example.knowyourtemple.view.service.BackgroundMusicService;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FragmentPlayMusic extends Fragment implements BackgroundMusicService.MusicPlayerCallback {

    private FragmentPlayMusicBinding binding;
    private Button playButton;
    private Button previousButton;
    private Button nextButton;
    private SeekBar seekBar;
    private int currentPosition = 0;
    private boolean isPlaying = false;
    private ArrayList<PojoMusic> musicList;
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable runnable;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private BackgroundMusicService backgroundMusicService;
    private BackgroundMusicService.MusicPlayerCallback callback;

    private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            if (iBinder instanceof BackgroundMusicService.LocalBinder) {
                BackgroundMusicService.LocalBinder binder = (BackgroundMusicService.LocalBinder) iBinder;
                backgroundMusicService = binder.getService();
                callback = FragmentPlayMusic.this;  // Assign the callback from the fragment itself
                backgroundMusicService.setCallback(callback);  // Set the callback in the service
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            backgroundMusicService = null;
        }
    };

    public static FragmentPlayMusic newInstance(PojoMusic music, ArrayList<PojoMusic> musicList) {
        FragmentPlayMusic fragment = new FragmentPlayMusic();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable("PojoMusic", music);
        args.putSerializable("MusicList", musicList);
        args.putInt("StartPosition", 0); // Add the start position argument
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentPlayMusicBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        PojoMusic music = (PojoMusic) getArguments().getSerializable("PojoMusic");
        musicList = (ArrayList<PojoMusic>) getArguments().getSerializable("MusicList");
        binding.setMusic(music);
        Glide.with(requireContext())
                .load(music.getImg())
                .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_setting_banner)
                .into(binding.video);

        binding.playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (isPlaying) {
                    pauseMusic();
                } else {
                    startMusic();
                }
                togglePlayButtonImage();
            }
        });
        bindMusicService();

        binding.previousbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                playPreviousSong();
            }
        });

        binding.nextbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                playNextSong();
            }
        });

        seekBar = binding.seekBar;

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            /*    if (fromUser) {
                    seekToPosition(progress);
                }*/
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                int progress = seekBar.getProgress();
                seekToPosition(progress);
            }

        });
    }

    public void playPreviousSong() {
        if (musicList != null && musicList.size() > 1) {
            currentPosition--;
            if (currentPosition < 0) {
                currentPosition = musicList.size() - 1; // Wrap around to the last song
            }
            playCurrentSong();
            startMusic();
        }
    }
    public void playNextSong() {
        if (musicList != null && musicList.size() > 1) {
            currentPosition++;
            if (currentPosition >= musicList.size()) {
                currentPosition = 0; // Wrap around to the first song
            }
            playCurrentSong();
            startMusic();
        }
    }


    private void playCurrentSong() {
        if (musicList != null && currentPosition >= 0 && currentPosition < musicList.size()) {
            PojoMusic currentMusic = musicList.get(currentPosition);
            binding.setMusic(currentMusic);

            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                }
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }

            initializeMediaPlayer();
            startMusic(); // Call startMusic() after initializing the MediaPlayer
        }
    }

    private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
        PojoMusic music = (PojoMusic) getArguments().getSerializable("PojoMusic");
        String songResourceName = music.getSongResourceName();
        int songResourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(songResourceName, "raw", requireActivity().getPackageName());

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), songResourceId);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                playNextSong();
            }
        });
    }











    private void startMusic() {
        isPlaying = true;
        String fileName = binding.getMusic().getSongResourceName();
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(requireContext(), BackgroundMusicService.class);
        serviceIntent.setAction(BackgroundMusicService.ACTION_START);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("FileName", fileName);
        String songName = binding.getMusic().getName();
        serviceIntent.putExtra("SongName", songName);
        // Get the last known position from the service and pass it to the intent
        BackgroundMusicService musicService = getMusicService();
        if (musicService != null) {
            int currentPosition = musicService.getCurrentPosition();
            serviceIntent.putExtra("Position", currentPosition);
        }

        requireActivity().startService(serviceIntent);
        updateSeekBarProgress();
    }

    private void pauseMusic() {
        isPlaying = false;
        if (backgroundMusicService != null) {
            backgroundMusicService.pauseMusic();
        }
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }

    private void togglePlayButtonImage() {
        if (isPlaying) {
            binding.playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_pause_24);
        } else {
            binding.playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_play_arrow_24);
        }
    }


    private void updateSeekBarProgress() {
        if (handler != null && runnable != null) {
            // Remove any existing callbacks to prevent multiple Runnables running simultaneously
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                BackgroundMusicService musicService = getMusicService();
                if (musicService != null) {
                    int currentPosition = musicService.getCurrentPosition();
                    int duration = musicService.getDuration();
                    seekBar.setMax(duration);
                    seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
                    // Notify the callback with the progress values
                    callback.onProgress(currentPosition, duration);
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
    }

    private BackgroundMusicService getMusicService() {
        return backgroundMusicService;
    }

    private void seekToPosition(int position) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(requireContext(), BackgroundMusicService.class);
        serviceIntent.setAction(BackgroundMusicService.ACTION_SEEK);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("Position", position);
        requireActivity().startService(serviceIntent);
    }

    private void bindMusicService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(requireContext(), BackgroundMusicService.class);
        requireActivity().bindService(serviceIntent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        if (backgroundMusicService != null) {
            backgroundMusicService.setCallback(this);
        }
    }

    private void unbindMusicService() {
        requireActivity().unbindService(connection);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        // Remove any pending callbacks from the handler
        if (handler != null && runnable != null) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }

        // Unbind the service when the fragment is destroyed
        unbindMusicService();

        // Stop the service when the fragment is destroyed
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(requireContext(), BackgroundMusicService.class);
        requireActivity().stopService(serviceIntent);

        binding = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(int duration) {
        seekBar.setMax(duration);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgress(int progress, int max) {
        seekBar.setProgress(progress);
        seekBar.setMax(max);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNextSong() {
        playNextSong();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviousSong() {
       playPreviousSong();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResumeSong() {
        startMusic();
        togglePlayButtonImage();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPauseSong() {
        pauseMusic();
        togglePlayButtonImage();
    }
}
```

I want my notification to work like Spotify

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).